# USER update after clicking the activation link in the email

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have standard Laravel registration system.
I need to update the column enable (enable = 1) for the user after clicking on the link from the email.

My migration:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->bigInteger('company_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('company_id')->references('id')->on('companies')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->boolean('enable')->default(0);
            $table->string('name', 120)->nullable();
            $table->string('surname', 120)->nullable();
            $table->string('email', 120)->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->bigInteger('counter')->default(0);
            $table->string('url_address', 160);
            $table->string('ip', 25)->nullable();
            $table->boolean('isCompany')->default(0);
            $table->boolean('isMailing')->default(0);
            $table->text('content')->nullable();
            $table->string('nip1', 12)->nullable();
            $table->string('business1', 120)->nullable();
            $table->string('phone1', 60)->nullable();
            $table->string('street1', 150)->nullable();
            $table->string('number1', 8)->nullable();
            $table->string('postal_code1', 12)->nullable();
            $table->string('city1', 100)->nullable();
            $table->bigInteger('country_id1')->default(0);
            $table->bigInteger('provincial_id1')->default(0);
            $table->string('nip2', 12)->nullable();
            $table->string('business2', 120)->nullable();
            $table->string('phone2', 60)->nullable();
            $table->string('street2', 150)->nullable();
            $table->string('number2', 8)->nullable();
            $table->string('postal_code2', 12)->nullable();
            $table->string('city2', 100)->nullable();
            $table->bigInteger('country_id2')->default(0);
            $table->bigInteger('provincial_id2')->default(0);
            $table->string('nip3', 12)->nullable();
            $table->string('business3', 120)->nullable();
            $table->string('phone3', 60)->nullable();
            $table->string('street3', 150)->nullable();
            $table->string('number3', 8)->nullable();
            $table->string('postal_code3', 12)->nullable();
            $table->string('city3', 100)->nullable();
            $table->bigInteger('country_id3')->default(0);
            $table->bigInteger('provincial_id3')->default(0);
            $table->decimal('cash', 9, 2)->default(0);
            $table->decimal('lng', 10, 8)->default(0);
            $table->decimal('lat', 10, 8)->default(0);
            $table->boolean('enable_map')->default(0);
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->engine = "InnoDB";
        });
```

How can I do this? By default, users are set to enable = 0

Comment: Are you trying to do email verification?

Comment: Instead of create call you should make update call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you have your users table built and `enabled` will work fine for your purposes. Next you have a few options, the simplest would be upon registration fire off an email with a link along the lines of www.my.site/activate?token=MD5TOKEN, where the md5 token is a md5 hash of the email they signed up with. Then to activate it when they hit that route take their email hash it and compare, if they're not signed in make them sign in before you do this. After that if it matches activate it.

The alternative would be to create another table titled `activation_tokens` which stores an email and a randomly generated token that you can regenerate many times as well as a `is_used` column.

Edit to answer comment:

```
DB::table('users')
            ->where('email', $email)
            ->update(['enabled' => 1]);
```

Comment: I use oryginal Laravel Auth and I have http://sample.com/email/verify/2?expires=1558041020&signature=cfbb22ff13be8526e561c057d4a0e8d6d221c420d4ed6a4ef627800ea4906dda - after this url I wand update enable = 1

Comment: Email verification is included in Laravel starting in 5.7: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/verification

Otherwise, setup your route for the email verification to determine which user it is and set enable=1

Comment: Ok, I make route and this: public function userActive(Request $request, User $user)
    {
        echo "XXXXX".$request->user()->email;
        $d = new User();
        $d->update([
            'enable' => 1,
            'id' => $request->user()->id
        ]);

        dd($user);
        // Redirect
    } - I see result from userActive - but record enable in DB is not update :( I have enable in $fillable in Users

Answer (score 0):

Try to change userActive() function.

```
  public function userActive(Request $request, User $user) {
        echo "XXXXX".$request->user()->email; 
        $user->update([ 'enable' => 1]); 
        dd($user); // Redirect 
    }
```